# How to crop / edit mp3 files

Tags: command-line, mp3

I have mp3 file but while recording mp3 file they give 10 secs of blank and we need to crop this blank from mp3 file

any suggestion for editing or cropping mp3 files or any commandline ?

thanks

Comment: `ffmpeg -i InputFile -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:32 OutputFile`

this command line solved my problem thanks for your kind replies

Comment: It may be answered elsewhere, but this result showed up my google search.

Answer (score 1):

Kdenlive is a nice video editing program. it is available in the repo
`sudo apt-get install kdenlive`

Comment: does it support mp3 files for cropping ?

Comment: did you mean? mp4mp3 is audio only, no?  yes it crops and transforms and you can add audio files also

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend audacity for audio files (inc. mp3).  It's not command line (or at least I've never used it that way) but gui, handling ogg vorbis, mp2, mp3, wav, aiff, and eu.

Comment: samoyed; `sudo apt install samoyed` :)

Comment: merci for the reply! Never heard of that breed, but looks nice! Merci! Or should I say "sh -h now"?